# XNA 4.0 - Using premade .xnb font files

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, xna-content-pipeline

Basically, for our college project, we need to use a font in xna. The only problem is that we are not allowed to install it due to admin rights.

Is it possible to use and load the .xnb file that gets created as the font. Using spritefont gives errors as it searches for the font in windows.

(The .xnb file will be created on someones personal machine beforehand.)

Comment: Yes you can do that. The `.spritefont` gives error because its not compiled to `.xnb`. You could also use a spritesheet with a font, here is how I do it: [code](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BmBmgV62) [image](http://i.imgur.com/lDUbMtf.png). I made that spritesheet using [BMFC tool](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/)

Comment: First you need to Call `Font.Initialize()` in your `Initialize` and `Font.Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("FontSprite");` in your `LoadContent` method. Then you can call `Font.DrawString(spriteBatch, "my text", 1.15f, new Vector2(100, 200), Color.Snow);` in your `Draw` method.

Comment: This tool [XNA Formatter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xnbbuilder/) can also compile `.spritefont` to `.xnb` but it seems like it requires XNA 4.0 installed, so that you have the content pipeline dependencies set.

Comment: I have the .xnb file. Is there no way of using it easily like I use a spritefont, or do I need to write a new class handling the font?

Comment: `.xnb` is a `compiled` file, so no, of course you can't edit it. What would the purpose of it be then. What I showed you has nothing to do with `.spritefont` or `.xnb`. It is how you could use an image as a font.

Comment: As other says, if you compile the spritefont to an XNB on a different machine and just copy it over, it will work just fine. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Copy your compiled (.xnb) font file to your content. And make the same filename as .spritefont file.

If you can't compile any fonts, use third party applications compiling those files.

Edit:
Spritefont files are used to explain to the compiler, how that .ttf file should be compiled. (font size, chars, etc.)